# Crawling websites which ask for authentication

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I followed this https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/HttpAuthenticationSchemes link for crawling few websites by providing username and password

Work around:I have set the auth-configuration in httpclient-auth.xml file:

```
<auth-configuration>
<credentials username="xyz" password="xyz">
<default realm="domain" />
<authscope host="www.gmail.com" port="80"/>
</credentials>
</auth-configuration>
```

ii)Define httpclient property in both nutch-site.xml and nutch-default.xml

```
<property>
<name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|html|js)|index-(basic|anchor)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
```

iii) Also have defined the auth configuration file in nutch-site.xml.

```
<property>
<name>http.auth.file</name>
<value>httpclient-auth.xml</value>
<description>Authentication configuration file for 'protocol-httpclient' plugin.
</description>
```

I'm not able to crawl it and getting no error..

Requirements: I want to crawl websites like gmail.com or yahoomail.com or anything which asks for authentication.

Where am i going wrong, am i choosing wrong websites for crawling

( if yes please provide me the websites which asks for authentication I'll register for it)

(if no how can i crawl my gmail or facebook accounts)

Answer (score 3):

Few points which will help you in resolving this issue:

1) Yes you have chosen wrong website to crawl and index try some different websites.

2) Nutch only support ***NTLM, Basic or Digest authentication***. It do not support the **Form Based Authentication**. The sites that you are trying use have Form based Authentication.

3) To implement Form Based Authentication you will have to customize your Nutch code.

I am sure following 2 links will help you in making some progress in this issue that you are facing:

http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/2014/05/nutch-solr-formed-based-authentication.html

http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-configure-nutch-in-eclipse-for.html

Comment: Two quick question: 1* can i use my gmail or yahoo accounts for form authentication..?If yes, please provide me the exact link to usel. if no, pls provide any links and i'l register for it. 2* I went through that 1st link where to put those java files and how nutch will come to know about it..?

Comment: 1) do you want to crawl your gmail account and yahoo account?
If yes, Then yes this is possible using http post authentication mechanism but for that you will have to modify the Nutch code.
2) The first link conatins the link for lifelongprogrammer link. Follow that blog :
Those series of articles talks about how to extend Nutch2 to support Http Post Form Authentication.