# Crawling authentication based pages using apache nutch

Tags: authentication, solr, nutch

How can I crawl authentication based pages using nutch? I have done all the required settings in nutch-site.xml, nutch-default.xml and httpclient-auth.xml. Still it shows the following:

```
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
Stopping at depth=1 - no more URLs to fetch.
```

I have followed the the following links
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183951/crawling-websites-which-ask-for-authentication),
[link 2](http://gingercart.com/Home/search-and-crawl/nutch-custom-authentication-cookies-session-management-to-crawl-secure-enterprise-websites). But still my crawler doesn't crawl the pages. Is there any way in which I can use an API key to help crawling?

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure `httpclient-auth.xml`
Here is an example for the solr UI with authentication, made the same for your sites.

```
<auth-configuration>
   <credentials username="solr" password="xxx">
      <authscope host="localhost" port="8983"/>
   </credentials>
</auth-configuration>
```

See multiple example in this file and try them

And add into nutch-site

```
<property>
<name>http.auth.file</name>
<value>httpclient-auth.xml</value>
<description>Authentication configuration file for 'protocol-httpclient' plugin.
</description>
```

Comment: I have added the required credentials but it  seems the site I want to crawl has blocked its crawling in robots.txt. If so how do I proceed?

Comment: It seems to me that if the site refuses via robots.txt you can do nothing or modify it if you have the rights
see this http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Ignoring-Robots-txt-td619276.html

Comment: what authentication have you configure?