# Apache Nutch Redirect error (apache/nutch docker image) : Redirect(s) not handled due to configuration

Tags: docker, nutch

I am using Apache Nutch crawler (docker image - apache/nutch:release-1.17) and I am able to crawl and index the data into the Elastic search for the site listed below :

> http://nutch.apache.org/ , https://www.apple.com/

I am facing an issue while crawling (https://sites.ey.com/).

> Result of Parse check
> `nutch# bin/nutch parsechecker -dumpText https://sites.ey.com/ > logs/parsechecker.log Fetch failed with protocol status: temp_moved(13), lastModified=0: https://sites.ey.com/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F Redirect(s) not handled due to configuration. Max Redirects to handle per config: 100 Number of Redirects handled: 0`

> nutch-site.xml

```html
    <configuration>
   <property>
      <name>http.agent.name</name>
      <value>spider</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>http.robots.agents</name>
      <value>Baiduspider</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>http.robot.rules.whitelist</name>
      <value>sites.ey.com,nutch,nature.com,apple.com</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>http.robots.403.allow</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>plugin.includes</name>
      <value>protocol-(http|httpclient)|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|scoring-opic|indexer-elastic</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
      <value>false</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>elastic.host</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>elastic.port</name>
      <value>9300</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>elastic.cluster</name>
      <value>elasticsearch</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>elastic.index</name>
      <value>crawltest</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>http.agent.version</name>
      <value>Nutch-1.17</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fetcher.threads.fetch</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fetcher.server.delay</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>fetcher.min.crawl.delay</name>
     <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>fetcher.max.crawl.delay</name>
     <value>120</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>page.load.delay</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>take.screenshot</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>screenshot.location</name>
      <value>crawltest</value>
    </property>
    <!-- Page redirect Settings -->
    <property>
      <name>http.redirect.max</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>fetcher.redirect.dedupcache.seconds</name>
      <value>5000</value>
    </property>
    
    <!-- Proxy Settings -->
    <property>
      <name>http.proxy.username</name>
      <value>xyz</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>http.proxy.password</name>
      <value>xyz</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>http.proxy.host</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>http.proxy.port</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>http.proxy.realm</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>http.proxy.type</name>
      <value>HTTP</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

> I have also defined the site credentials in "httpclient-auth.xml"

> fetch command log :

```html
2020-12-14 19:33:43,622 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=1, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
2020-12-14 19:33:43,622 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueues - * queue: sites.ey.com
2020-12-14 19:33:43,623 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   maxThreads    = 1
2020-12-14 19:33:43,623 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   inProgress    = 1
2020-12-14 19:33:43,623 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   crawlDelay    = 10000
2020-12-14 19:33:43,623 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   minCrawlDelay = 0
2020-12-14 19:33:43,623 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   nextFetchTime = 1607974422407
2020-12-14 19:33:43,623 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   now           = 1607974423623
2020-12-14 19:33:43,623 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   0. https://sites.ey.com/sites/DS_Tax/Pages/Home.aspx
2020-12-14 19:33:44,297 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,297 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,297 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.writeRequestLine(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,298 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.generateRequestLine(HttpConnection, String, String, String, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,300 DEBUG wire.header - >> "GET / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,301 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,301 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,301 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,301 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.writeRequestHeaders(HttpState,HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,302 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addRequestHeaders(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,302 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addUserAgentRequestHeaders(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,302 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addHostRequestHeader(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,302 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Adding Host request header
2020-12-14 19:33:44,303 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addCookieRequestHeader(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,337 TRACE httpclient.HttpState - enter HttpState.getCookies()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,338 TRACE cookie.CookieSpec - enter CookieSpecBase.match(String, int, String, boolean, Cookie[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,338 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.addProxyConnectionHeader(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,339 DEBUG wire.header - >> "Accept-Language: en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,339 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,340 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,340 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,340 DEBUG wire.header - >> "Accept-Charset: utf-8,iso-8859-1;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,340 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,341 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,341 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,341 DEBUG wire.header - >> "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,341 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,341 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,342 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,342 DEBUG wire.header - >> "Accept-Encoding: x-gzip, gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,342 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,342 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,342 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,343 DEBUG wire.header - >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)/Nutch-1.18-SNAPSHOT[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,343 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,343 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,343 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,343 DEBUG wire.header - >> "Host: sites.ey.com[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,343 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.print(String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,344 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,344 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,344 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.writeLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,344 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[])
2020-12-14 19:33:44,344 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.write(byte[], int, int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,344 DEBUG wire.header - >> "[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,345 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,528 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,528 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,528 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.readLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,529 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,529 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,625 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=1, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
2020-12-14 19:33:44,625 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueues - * queue: sites.ey.com
2020-12-14 19:33:44,625 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   maxThreads    = 1
2020-12-14 19:33:44,626 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   inProgress    = 1
2020-12-14 19:33:44,626 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   crawlDelay    = 10000
2020-12-14 19:33:44,626 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   minCrawlDelay = 0
2020-12-14 19:33:44,626 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   nextFetchTime = 1607974422407
2020-12-14 19:33:44,626 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   now           = 1607974424626
2020-12-14 19:33:44,627 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   0. https://sites.ey.com/sites/DS_Tax/Pages/Home.aspx
2020-12-14 19:33:44,790 DEBUG wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 302 Found[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,790 DEBUG wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 302 Found[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,791 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponseHeaders(HttpState,HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,791 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.getResponseInputStream()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,791 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HeaderParser.parseHeaders(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,791 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,791 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,791 DEBUG wire.header - << "Content-Length: 178[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,791 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "Location: https://sites.ey.com/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "X-SharePointHealthScore: 0[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "SPRequestGuid: b64e979f-0081-b000-92a2-1477992fe6c0[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "request-id: b64e979f-0081-b000-92a2-1477992fe6c0[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "MS-CV: n5dOtoEAALCSohR3mS/mwA.0[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 DEBUG wire.header - << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,792 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "SPRequestDuration: 32[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "SPIisLatency: 0[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.20802[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: EA8D06FD4BFD4EDABD584B342F8D81B3 Ref B: MAA01EDGE0405 Ref C: 2020-12-14T19:33:44Z[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 DEBUG wire.header - << "Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 19:33:44 GMT[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readLine(InputStream, String)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,793 TRACE httpclient.HttpParser - enter HttpParser.readRawLine()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,794 DEBUG wire.header - << "[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,794 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.processResponseHeaders(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,794 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.processCookieHeaders(Header[], HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,794 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponseBody(HttpState, HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,794 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.readResponseBody(HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,794 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.getResponseInputStream()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,794 TRACE httpclient.HttpMethodBase - enter HttpMethodBase.canResponseHaveBody(int)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,795 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Redirect required
2020-12-14 19:33:44,803 DEBUG wire.content - << "<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,804 DEBUG wire.content - << "<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://sites.ey.com/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F">here</a>.</h2>[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,804 DEBUG wire.content - << "</body></html>[\r][\n]"
2020-12-14 19:33:44,804 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Resorting to protocol version default close connection policy
2020-12-14 19:33:44,805 DEBUG httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Should NOT close connection, using HTTP/1.1
2020-12-14 19:33:44,805 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.isResponseAvailable()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,805 TRACE httpclient.HttpConnection - enter HttpConnection.releaseConnection()
2020-12-14 19:33:44,805 DEBUG httpclient.HttpConnection - Releasing connection back to connection manager.
2020-12-14 19:33:44,805 TRACE httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - enter HttpConnectionManager.releaseConnection(HttpConnection)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,805 DEBUG httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Freeing connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=https://sites.ey.com]
2020-12-14 19:33:44,805 TRACE httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - enter HttpConnectionManager.ConnectionPool.getHostPool(HostConfiguration)
2020-12-14 19:33:44,806 DEBUG util.IdleConnectionHandler - Adding connection at: 1607974424805
2020-12-14 19:33:44,806 DEBUG httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2020-12-14 19:33:44,989 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'fetcher', using default
2020-12-14 19:33:45,628 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=1, fetchQueues.totalSize=1, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
2020-12-14 19:33:45,628 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueues - * queue: sites.ey.com
2020-12-14 19:33:45,637 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   maxThreads    = 1
2020-12-14 19:33:45,637 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   inProgress    = 0
2020-12-14 19:33:45,638 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   crawlDelay    = 10000
2020-12-14 19:33:45,638 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   minCrawlDelay = 0
2020-12-14 19:33:45,638 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   nextFetchTime = 1607974434986
2020-12-14 19:33:45,638 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   now           = 1607974425638
2020-12-14 19:33:45,639 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueue -   0. https://sites.ey.com/sites/DS_Tax/Pages/Home.aspx
2020-12-14 19:33:46,640 INFO  fetcher.Fetcher - -activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=1, fetchQueues.totalSize=1, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
2020-12-14 19:33:46,640 INFO  fetcher.FetchItemQueues - * queue: sites.ey.com
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Add the option `-followRedirects` to make parsechecker follow redirects. The tool was meant to test the parsing and does behave differently than Fetcher. See the command-line help which is shown if no arguments are found (`nutch parsechecker`).

Comment: Thanks for your response! -followRedirects definitely helped me and now I have started getting an Authentication error. I am trying to follow  link for setting authentication: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/HttpAuthenticationSchemes.  Is there a way to set "Auth token" to the request header of Nutch crawler ?

Comment: <additionalPostHeaders> in [httpclient-auth.xml](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/4c7d4229aecbba43b6430e2517a841fdcd5e223b/conf/httpclient-auth.xml.template#L78)?

Comment: > Currently i have done this config

conf/nutch-site.xml

<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>      <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|scoring-opic|indexer-elastic</value>
</property>

---------
   
conf/httpclient-auth.xml

<auth-configuration>
 <credentials username="xyz" password="pqr">
  <default/>
 </credentials>
</auth-configuration>

Comment: HTTPPOST header properties is not available in the docker image "apache/nutch-latest", maybe I need to checkout the Nutch project and then modify to resolve this authentication issue.

Comment: I found this link with a similar Auth issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183951/crawling-websites-which-ask-for-authentication

Comment: [HTTP Post Authentication](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/HttpPostAuthentication) was added to Nutch in 2015 (included in Nutch 1.10). The configuration file is included in the Docker image at `/nutch/conf/httpclient-auth.xml`

Comment: I have done all the configurations mentioned in the HttpPostAuthentication Link but still it's not working for me. Could you please tell me what can be wrong or what more details I need to share so that we can progress?